# send image over java socket

Tags: java, sockets, javax.imageio

I'm going to send webcam captures from client to server with socket.
In this code client send images with `BufferedImage` and server will received these images then save them as a jpg file.
But apparently Buffered image in server side is not null only for first frame then it will be null!
I`m really confused about that and don't know why it happens.
Here is server side and client side code:
server:

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private  ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private int port = 8083;
    private  Socket socket;
    private BufferedImage bufferedImage;

    int i =0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            if (socket.isConnected())
                System.out.println("client accepted");
            while (true) {
                bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());
                if (bufferedImage != null){
                    System.out.println("done!");
                    File output = new File(i + ".jpg");
                    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", output);
                    i++;
                }else
                    System.out.println("null!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

client:

```
public class WebcamClientThread extends Thread{
    private Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedImage bufferedImage;

    WebcamClientThread(String ip, int port){
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());//640,480
        webcam.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       try{
           socket = new Socket(ip,port);
           while(true){
               bufferedImage = webcam.getImage();
               ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,"jpg", socket.getOutputStream());
               Thread.sleep(30);
           }

       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks fairly nefarious :/.

Comment: The problem is that you need to know where the JPEG streams start/end. You can easily fix that, by extending your "protocol" with the length of each stream before the actual JPEG data (hint: you need to buffer the data to memory/disk to do this). Make sure to properly reposition before each read on the server side, as `ImageIO.read()` may not read exactly the number of bytes you expect. PS: If you know your client will always send you properly encoded JPEGs, there's no reason why the server should use `ImageIO` to decode and re-encode them... Just write the images directly to disk.